# Modularize (refactor) Linq queries

Tags: c#, linq

I have a few Linq queries. Semantically, they are

1. a join b join c join d where filter1(a) && filter2(c) && filter3(d)
2. a join b join c        where filter1(a) && filter2(c)
3. a join b join c join e where filter1(a) && filter2(c) && filter4(e)

...

I want to be able to factor out the shared part:

```
a join b join c where filter1(a) && filter2(c)
```

and dynamically append `join d` and `filter3(d)`

Is there a way to do this?  I am already using the Predicate Builder to dynamically build conditionals (filters).

EDIT: I am using Linq-to-SQL.

EDIT: The base query looks like:

```
from a in As.AsExpandable()
join b in Bs on a.Id equals b.PId
join c in Cs on b.Id equals c.PId
where filter1(a) && filter2(b) && filter3(c)
select new A { ... }
```

filters are predicates in Predicate Builder. The type of the query is `IQueryable<A>`.

Next, I'd like to join this with d

```
from a in BaseQuery()
join d in D on a.Id equals d.PId
```

Currently `join d ..` causes a compilation error:

> The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect. Type inference failed in the call to Join

Comment: Which Linq provider are you using?

Comment: @DoctaJonez: Does that really matter?

Comment: @Steven absolutely. Many things will break if the provider is anything other than Linq2Objects. The Linq provider model is haphazard at best currently, especially because it's a nightmare for developers to implement having seen Ayende spending months on it with RavenDB.

Comment: @Chris: Perhaps I misinterpreted the question, but please look at my answer and tell me how this will break on different providers.

Answer (score 3):

Your example is a bit vague, but it is easy to create a method that returns an `IQueryable<T>` and reuse that method, if that’s what you mean. Here is an example:

```
// Reusable method
public IQueryable<SomeObject> GetSomeObjectsByFilter(Context c)
{
     return
         from someObject in context.SomeObjects
         where c.B.A.Amount < 1000
         where c.Roles.Contains(r => r.Name == "Admin")
         select someObject;
}
```

You can reuse this method in other places like this:

```
var q =
    from c in GetSomeObjectsByFilter(context)
    where !c.D.Contains(d => d.Items.Any(i => i.Value > 100))
    select c;
```

Because the way `IQueryable` works, only the final query (the collection that you start iterating) will trigger a call to the database, which allows you to build a highly maintainable system by reusing business logic that gets effectively executed inside the database, whiteout the loss of any performance.

I do this all the time and it improves the maintainability of my code big time. It works no matter which O/RM tool you run, because there is no difference in `Queryable<T>` composition, between writing the query in one peace, or splitting it out to different methods.

Note that you do sometimes need some smart transformations to get the duplicate parts in a single method. Things that might help are returning grouped sets, and returning a set of a different type, than what you think you need. This sounds a bit vaque, but just post a question here at SO when you have problems splitting up a method. There are enough people here that can help you with that.

Comment: This answer is overly vague to state anything specific, but this would very likely not work if the provider is Linq2Entities (aka EntityFramework) as it will try to execute your methods in the database instead of at execution time.

Comment: @Chris: I'm not sure I follow you. What do you mean by "execute ... at execution time". Of course EF will convert the final query to SQL and let the database execute it. That's the whole purpose of EF, so I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: I always thought that depended on the Where implementation actually, not IQueryable (which is an interface).

Comment: @Steven: The filter expressions might trip EF up.  The problem is that `filter(x)` will not compile unless `filter` is a Func.  A query provider will need `filter` to be an `Expression` to be able to parse the Expression tree and convert to SQL.  You can get around this using [AsExpandable](http://tomasp.net/blog/linq-expand.aspx) which comes as part of [LinqKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx).

Comment: @DoctaJonez: When the OP's `filter1`, `filter2`, and `filter3` are delegates, it will indeed not work. I didn't interpret his question like that. I just assumed that `filter1` was just his way of describing that he needed a where clause. But now I understand what you and @Chris are pointing at, and again, in that case you are absolutely right: that will definitely not work. I will change my answer to make the example more clear, and less ambiguous.

Comment: @Steven: I need to create a new domain to capture a join b join c.  You are assuming A contains property B and B property contains C, which isn't true.

Comment: @Candy: I don't assume anything. Just showing what is the general way to split up your query over multiple methods. In the case of your update, let the method return a `IQueryable<Tuple<A, B>>`.

Comment: @Steven: I am still on 3.5 in which Tuple is not available. I tried adding non DB properties to A to capture the info of interest in B and C such that I can return IQueryable<A>.  However, this doesn't join with D.  Exception: The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect. Type inference failed in the call to 'Join'.  Thanks.

Comment: @Candy: You can create a `Tuple<A, B>` class easily yourself. Or you can name it `Pair<A, B>`, or create something like this: `public class AAndB { public A A { get; set; } public B B { get; set; } }`.

Comment: @Steven: when you type c.B.A, you are implicitly assuming B is a property of C and A is a property of B.  In my case, their relationships are not modelled.  A and B are joined by ids not objects.  I also noticed that there're no join statements in your example, which are probably taken care of internally by the relation mappings.

Comment: @Candy: If you can, always model the relationships in your database. This makes querying so much easier, and your LINQ queries so much more readable.

Comment: @Steven: I hear you. By not modelling a relationship, I meant in the domain objects, some of the relationships are one way, not two way.  This makes many-to-many relationship easier to maintain.  Does it mean your strategy relies on the relationships being mapped in the domain models?

Answer (score 1):

I can answer half your question easily.  Linq makes it simple to append .where clauses to an existing query.

Example:

```
var x = db.Table1.where(w => w.field1 == nTestValue);
x = x.where(w => w.field2 == nTestValue2);
```

I believe you can do the joins as well but I have to go find an example in some old code.  I'll look if nobody else jumps in with it soon.

Comment: I am stuck on the other half.